# Crosswalk Efficiency

Tags: code-golf

A standard road intersection contains 4 sidewalk corners and four crosswalks connecting them. It could also have 2 diagonal walks.

```
    sRRRRs
    iOOOOi
    dAAAAd
    eDDDDe
side0----1walk
ROAD|\  /|ROAD
ROAD| \/ |ROAD
ROAD| /\ |ROAD
ROAD|/  \|ROAD
side2----3walk
    wRRRRw
    aOOOOa
    lAAAAl
    kDDDDk
```

Not all 6 crosswalks are needed to let pedestrians get from any corner to any other (assuming no jaywalking). It's better for traffic and cheaper for the highway department if there are fewer crosswalks. However, it is better for pedestrians if they can get across faster.

Let L be the total length of the crosswalks present in the intersection. Assume the intersection is a unit square, so the length of orthogonal walks is 1 and for diagonal walks it's sqrt(2).

Let W be the average distance a pedestrian needs to walk when crossing the intersection. Each corner fills up with pedestrians evenly and each pedestrian at a corner is randomly headed for one of the 3 other corners with equal chance.

When L and W are low we have an efficient intersection. Let `E = 1 / (W * L)` be the crosswalk efficiency of a particular set of crosswalks. Higher E means more efficient.

### Goal

Write a program that takes in a list of present crosswalks and outputs the efficiency.

Input will come from stdin in the form `01 32 21` (for example), which represents an intersection with crosswalks from corners 0 to 1, 3 to 2, and 2 to 1 (in a Z). Output to stdout.

Running your program might look something like

```
$ crosswalk.mylanguage 01 23
0.0
```

### Scoring

This is code golf. The submission with the fewest characters wins.

### Details

- Pedestrians always stay on the crosswalks and always take the shortest route.
- Pedestrians can change direction where the diagonals meet (and at corners).
- If all corners aren't connected take W to be infinity (and E to be 0).
- The input crosswalk edges are always unique and there are only up to 6.
- The input or corner order doesn't matter. `01 32 21` is the same as `23 21 10`.

Comment: Given the finite space of possible combinations, are precalculated values allowed?

Comment: What is the advantage of changing direction at the diagonals? The path would be longer!

Comment: Not if there's not a direct route...

Comment: If there are two diagonals, is a pedestrian allowed to change direction at the centre? If so, the best efficency is just the diagonals: `1/(   (2*sqrt(2))*(6*sqrt(2)/6)   )=1/4`. Otherwise it is three edges:`1/(3* (1+1+1+2+2+3)/6 )=1/5`

Comment: You may precalculate values for W and L but not for E.  Changing the efficiency function to say `E = 1 / (W*W*L)` should be doable in only a few extra characters.

Comment: @steveverrill Yes, the question says that's fine. And I want you to find the general efficiency, not the max.

Comment: What happens if the input is `03 32` so that there's no way to get to or from corner 1?

Comment: @ssdecontrol Then W is infinity and E is 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Python 3 - 424 characters

This uses precalculated values for W:

```py
u,s=list(map(list,[map(int,x) for x in input().split()])),2**.5
q,p,o,w,e,r=sum(u,[]),(2*s+1)/3,(s+1)/3,(2*s+3)/3,(s+3)/3,(5*s+1)/6
print(.0 if len(set(q))<4 or len(q)<5 and q[0]^q[1]==q[2]^q[3]!=3 else 1/({66:p,80:p,34:w,48:w,42:e,49:e,10:5/3,17:5/3,72:r,65:r,74:o,81:o,73:p,41:(s+2)/2,64:s,18:4/3,82:(s+2)/3,50:(s+6)/6}[sum([(0,1,8,32)[q[x]^q[x+1]] for x in range(0,len(q),2)])]*sum(map(lambda a:(1,s)[a[0]^a[1]==3],u))))
```

It can be run like this:

```
echo 32 01 31 | python3 filename.py
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 489

Uses all pairs shortest paths.

```
import re
R=re.sub
exec R("I"," in ",R("F","for ","""s,m,i=sum,map,int
r=2**.5/2
n=1e309
g=[0,1,1,n,r],[1,0,n,1,r],[1,n,0,1,r],[n,1,1,0,r],[r]*4+[0]
f="01021323"
o=lambda v:[list(v[x:x+2])FxIrange(0,len(v),2)]
v=o(f+"04142434")
q=m(sorted,R("12|21","14 24",R("03|30","04 34",raw_input())).split())
r=range(5)
u=[m(i,x)FxIv if x notIq]
l=s(g[i(y)][i(x)]Fy,xIq)
Fy,xIu:g[y][x]=n
FaIr:
 FbIr:
    FcIr:g[b][c]=min(g[b][a]+g[a][c],g[b][c])
w=s(g[i(y)][i(x)]Fy,xIo(f+"0312"))/6.
print 1/(w*l)"""))
```